# Transposing data in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of laboratory results. Each row corresponds to a time point of a subject (for example: row 1 is subject #1 at his first visit, row 2 is subject #1 at his second visit,...). In each row, I have values of 5 tests (test1, test2, ....) and for each test, I have in addition to the result, two columns of reference values of the test (normal low and high levels). I wish to transpose the data, in a way that each row will be identical for subject+visit+test, with two columns, the numerical result and the status (normal or not). I failed transposing the data. I managed to get all tests in a long format, but I couldn't save the reference values. How should I do it ? My alternative is a set of if statements, it's going to be very long !

Comment: Please can you post some sample data of what you have and what you want, along with the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

This question was also posted on communities.sas.com.
The two step process extracts data about PARAMCD (lab test code) and variable type (value and normal range limits) from the names.  PARAMCD becomes a new row id variable and V L and H are used to create new variable names when the data are transposed again to the more or less (CDISC SDTM) format.

```
data A;
   input ID Visit Group Test1 Test2 Test3 Test1_L Test1_H Test2_L Test2_H Test3_L Test3_H;
   datalines;
1 1 0 5 3 6.7 1 10 2 7 3 9
1 2 0 5.5 3.8 8.7 1 10 2 7 3 6
1 3 0 4.5 2.8 5.7 1 10 3 7 3 6
2 1 1 5 3 6.7 1 10 2 7 3 9
2 2 1 5.5 3.8 8.7 1 10 2 7 3 9
2 3 1 4.5 2.8 5.7 1 10 2 7 3 9
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=a out=b;
   by id visit group;
   run;
data b;
   set b;
   length paramcd $8 namecd $1;
   call scan(_name_,1,p,l,'_');
   paramcd = substrn(_name_,p,l);
   namecd  = coalesceC(substrn(_name_,p+l+1),'V');
   drop p l _name_;
   run;
proc sort data=b;
   by id visit group paramcd;
   run;
proc format;
   value $namecd 'V'='Value' 'H'='High' 'L'='Low';
   run;
proc transpose data=b out=c(drop=_name_);
   by id visit group paramcd;
   id namecd;
   format namecd $namecd.;
   var col1;
   run;
data c;
   set c;
   length RangeFL $1;
   if      n(low,value)  eq 2 and value lt low  then RangeFL='L';
   else if n(high,value) eq 2 and value gt high then RangeFL='H';
   else                                              RangeFL='N';
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```